# I found this example of a function that accepts a callback but it's not working?

Tags: callback

This code is similar to our previous mean() function, except in the
    following if block where we check to see if a callback has been
    provided. If it has, then the callback is applied to each value
    before being added to the total; otherwise, the total is calculated
    using just the values from the array given as the first argument 
    mean([2,5,7,11,4]); // this should just calculate the mean << 5.8
    mean([2,5,7,11,4],x => 2*x); << 11.6

```
function mean(array ,callback) {
  if (callback) {
    array.map( callback );
  }
  const total = array.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
  return total/array.length;
}
console.log(mean([2,5,7,11,4,5],x => 2*x));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function mean(array,callback) {
    if (callback) {
        array = array.map( callback );   // <--- note changes here
    }
    const total = array.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
    return total/array.length;
}
console.log(mean([2,5,7,11,4])); //5.8 fine
console.log(mean([2,5,7,11,4],x => 2*x)) // 11.6
```

You weren't off by much.  Check out the exact definition of [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)  The return value from that function is a ***new array*** with each element being the result of the callback function.

I will say, your question got me to review Array.prototype.map() and [passing callback functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function). Thanks!

Almost forgot.. See how simple my code is formatted? That makes it easy for someone to see what's going on quickly.  Recommend you do the same when posting questions here in the future.

Comment: awww! I have just joined this website and i don't know much about it . thanks for the help ! u are my daily hero !